# VBA, run same macro for multiple selection

Tags: vba, excel

I would like to update the dates at first column(A) if the values change in the same related row with the date.

I could do it for one cell at a time with the below code. However, when multiple cells are selected, macro stops running. Can you help me to upgrade below code to work for multiple cells too ?

I found codes that does what i want for predefined targets and ranges, but i want it to work without defining target or selection range in the code.

[image: Example]

```
Dim oldValue As Variant

'Get the old selected cell value
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
    oldValue = Target.Value
End Sub

'Update the date in first column when new value on selected cell
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)  
    If (Target.Count = 1) And Not (Target.Column = 1) And Not (Target.Value = oldValue) Then
        Cells(Target.Row, 1) = Date
    Else

    End If
End Sub
```

**Edit (from comments)**:

I want to be able to update the relevant dates if multiple cells are changed. For example, when copying the letter "x" into the range `C6,C8:C9`, the dates in `A6`, `A8` and `A9` should change. But when copying the letter "a" into those same cells, only `A6` and `A9` should change, because `C8` was already "a" before making the change.

Comment: Use a loop. Simples.

Comment: How dates are updated? Plus one day? Minus 10 days?

Comment: to the date when last change has made

Comment: Am I correct that you want to update selected cells to contain current date?

Comment: @JohnyL Yes, but if i change a cell. If I don't change the cell i want corresponding first column in the row should remain same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Dim dict As Object

'Get the old selected cell value
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
    Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    For Each cell In UsedRange.Cells
        dict.Add cell.Address, cell.Value
    Next cell
End Sub

'Update the date in first column when new value on selected cell
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Not (Target.Column = 1) Then
        For Each cell In Target.Cells
            If dict.exists(cell.Address) Then
                If dict(cell.Address) <> cell.Value Then
                    Application.EnableEvents = False
                    Cells(cell.Row, 1) = Date
                    Application.EnableEvents = True
                End If
            Else 'if the cell was not used before and this is a new row being filled
                Application.EnableEvents = False
                Cells(cell.Row, 1) = Date
                Application.EnableEvents = False
            End If
        Next cell
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: "Can you help me to upgrade below code to work for multiple cells too" - your suggestion will only work if a single cell is changed.

Comment: you mean when one cell changes, it updates all of the dates?

Comment: No, the OP wants to be able to update the relevant dates if multiple cells are changed.  Perhaps they are copying (from somewhere) the letter "x" into the range "C6,C8:C9", then they are wanting the dates in A6, A8 and A9 to change.  (But if they copied "a" to those same cells, instead of "x", only A6 and A9 would change because C8 was "a" before the copy.)

Comment: @YowE3K This is exactly what i am asking for. Thanks

Comment: Then please mark it as the correct answer, also you can upvote it by clicking the triangles. If you wanted to implement what YowE3K27 pointed, it will be more work. You should be creative in that case, you can have a hidden sheet and keep the old values there and then compare the cells changed, to me that is a better way, or you can use arrays or dictionaries to keep old values and compare.

Comment: I changed the answer, it will do mass paste now

Comment: @SOKRATES I think Ibo's updated code does exactly what you want. :)

Comment: @YowE3K yes, you are right, as I mentioned, I would have preferred a hidden worksheet to compare, it is less memory and higher performance if the usedrange gets huge, however, I did not have the main file to create the worksheet and implement the idea.

Comment: @YowE3K I wrapped the `else` block with `application.enableevents`, that block can actually be ignored since I am not sure what the asker wants to do with inserting values in the rows that have no dates already there. I assumed he wanted to print the date for the first time instead of changing a date

Comment: @Ibo , thanks for the answer . I could give it a try but somehow after some multiple copy and paste try, code was not working anymore. After adding  'Application.EnableEvents = True'  just before 'End Sub' solved that too.